# 1-D heat equation with different thermal diffusivity at different regions

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-conditions

I am trying to solve this 1-D heat equation in the interval [-L1,L2] with the follow conditions:thermal diffusivity=alpha1 between [-L1,0);thermal diffusivity=alpha2 between (0,L2].Boundary conditions: T=T0+T1*Sin(omega*t) at x=-L1 and x=L2; dT/dx=flux at x=0. What's the correct way to set this up?
Thanks.

Comment: Just play around a bit with `NDSolve`.

Comment: `between [L1,0)` you mean `[-L1,0]`  and then you say `Initial condition: T=T0+T1*Sin(omega*t)`  how could initial conditions have `t` in it? This makes it then `T=T0`, since `sin(0)=0` because `t=0` at initial conditions. As for solving, you can try to make the `thermal diffusivity` as `Piecewise` and see if NDSolve accepts it. So use BC for the whole bar as is, and plugin for `alpha` the `Piecwise` condition.

Comment: The FEM backend of NDSolve can definately treat discontinuous diffusion constants. @Nasser

Comment: I made some corrections to the question.

Comment: You've removed "Initial condition" from the question, but this doesn't clarify anything, what's the "T=T0+T1*Sin(omega*t)"? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  "T=T0+T1*Sin(omega*t)" refers to both initial and boundary conditions of oscillating temperatures outside [-L1,L2].  The problem I want to solve is how temperature changes inside [-L1,L2] when the diffusivities change and the flux changes.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

The 1D heat equation in `x` and `t`

```
pde = alpha[x]*D[u[x, t], x, x] - D[u[x, t], t] == 0
```

Its easiest for me to set up alpha as a function of `UnitStep`

```
alpha[x_] = alpha1 (UnitStep[x + L1] - UnitStep[x]) + alpha2 (UnitStep[x] - UnitStep[x - L2])
```

The boundary conditions.

```
bc1 = u[-L1, t] == T0 + T1 Sin[omega t]

bc2 = u[L2, t] == T0 + T1 Sin[omega t]
```

You did not have an initial condition and MMA didn't complain when I didn't add one, but I added one anyway.

```
ic = u[x, 0] == T0
```

Plug in some numbers

```
alpha1 = 1;
alpha2 = 2;
T0 = 1;
T1 = 2;
omega = 2;
L1 = 1;
L2 = 2;

NDSolve[{pde, bc1, bc2, ic}, u[x, t], {x, -L1, L2}, {t, 0, 20}] // Flatten;

u[x_, t_] = u[x, t] /. %

tp = Table[Plot[u[x, t], {x, -L1, L2}, PlotRange -> {-1, 3}], {t, 0, 20, .1}];
ListAnimate[tp]
```

[image]